# QGIS 3.16 and newer not commiting merge when string exceeds 255

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, merge, error

I have been developing a QGIS plugin with PyQt5 in QGIS 3.10 for a while now. The plugin gets layers from an api, displaying features of POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON (wtk) in layers. When the wtk-strings are over 255 in length I get a warning message, but it still stores the data and displays the features. But when I want to merge layers together the strings that are over 255 in length will not get saved. So when merging I lose all features that exceeds the string length. This is not a problem in 3.10 but in 3.16 and 3.18. In 3.10 all features get saved after merge.

I use `qgis:mergevectorlayers` when merging.

Example of error message when trying to merge layers:

Could not commit changes to layer Bærelag

Errors: ERROR: 50 feature(s) not added.

Provider errors:
Could not store attribute "Geometri, hjelpelinje": String of length 3786
exceeds maximum field length (255) "
"

[image: commit error]

Is there an easy workaround?

Edit:

The layers are temporary scratch layers and when using `qgis:mergevectorlayers` they become GeoPackages

Comment: use a geopackage rather than a shapefile

Comment: Could you please add the error message as text instead of picture?

Comment: @IanTurton im using a library spsifically created for the api I'm using. The library creates the shapefile. I'll add that I'm very new to QGIS and GIS in general

Comment: @IanTurton correction. The library creates temporary scratch layers.